# Accessing outlook.office365.com from standalone app using javamail and OAUTH2

Tags: azure, outlook, oauth, jakarta-mail

we have a standalone Java app that connects to outlook.office365.com using basic authorization.  It's a simple monitoring app.

I have been asked to move this to "modern" authorization, so that appears to be creating an Azure app to get an access token for OAUTH2.  I "think" I have all that setup properly, including the Microsoft graph APIs (delegated)

email
IMAP.AccessAsUser.All
offline_access
SMTP.Send

So I retrieve a access token from: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token) passing the client ID and secret with a client_credentials grant type.

After changing the java code to use OAUTH2 and using the token as the password, I receive a login failure.

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.5.4
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.4
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAP: disable AUTH=LOGIN
DEBUG IMAP: disable AUTH=PLAIN
DEBUG IMAP: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "outlook.office365.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [QgBMAEEAUAB...]
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+ 
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login, host=outlook.office365.com, user=craig.welton@xyz.com, password=<non-null>
A1 LOGIN craig.welton@xyz.com {1508+}
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25.....
A1 NO LOGIN failed.
```

Am I missing a step here?  Most posts I've read about accessing outlook are from a web app rather than a standalone.

Thanks in advance,
Craig

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same issue, got token with client_credentials grant_type and https://graph.microsoft.com/.default as scope. Got below error
```DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 command result: A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
jakarta.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.
 at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:708)```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the client_credentials grant type to obtain an access token. Because the client_credentials flow is usually used in a daemon without user participation, it generally needs to grant `application permissions` to the application instead of `delegating permissions`. And as far as I know : **OAuth access to IMAP, POP, SMTP AUTH protocols via OAuth2 client credentials grant flow is not supported.**

Therefore, I recommend you to use [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow), which requires you to obtain the authorization code in your browser, and then use the authorization code to redeem the access token.

Comment: Thanks Carl.  Our process is essentially a daemon as it reads inboxes every few minutes.  There is no browser interaction.  So, are you saying this is not possible?  Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

OAuth2 flow for client credentials is now supported for IMAP, POP, and SMTP as mentioned in the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#use-client-credentials-grant-flow-to-authenticate-imap-and-pop-connections).